# Suppress lacheck error

Tags: errors

How can I suppress a [`lacheck`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck) error on a single line of a file?

Using [`chktex`](http://baruch.ev-en.org/proj/chktex/), I know that I can add a comment at the end of a line to suppress a particular warning. For instance, if I want to suppress warning `#8`, I can use:

```
% chktex 8
```

Is there something equivalent that can be done using `lacheck`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot. Lacheck has nothing to support this.

To quote the man page:

> LaCheck  gets  confused  by  advanced  macros,  is fooled by simple macros, can't figure out if you use a non-standard way to switch italic on or off, does not like TeX at all, *does not provide any options to turn off specific warnings**,  and  is  at  best  a  crude approximation.
>
> Ideas  for  improvements and bug reports are very welcome.  Such should be directed to the maintainers, their email address is .

emphasis above is mine.